# How to prevent popups with Skybound.Gecko

Tags: c#, popup, gecko

I would like to ask is there a way to prevent popups or SSL errors?
Also Javascript popups (alerts, confirms etc)

Right now I have used this:

```
GeckoPreferences.User["browser.xul.error_pages.enabled"] = false;
GeckoPreferences.User["security.enable_ssl2"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.User["security.default_personal_cert"] = "Ask Never";
GeckoPreferences.User["security.warn_entering_weak"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.User["security.warn_viewing_mixed"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.User["dom.disable_open_during_load"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.User["dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.User["dom.popup_maximum"] = 0;
```

Sometimes there are SSL certificate errors and sometimes other things pop up, but I have no idea how to close them.

Please help me out, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you set error_pages.enabled to true it wont show you a messagebox but will show you a warning page.

```
GeckoPreferences.User["browser.xul.error_pages.enabled"] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to implement and replace alert and promt interfaces:)